# Creating a table with js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

OK, I am very new to these things. I thought I got the DOM sense right but my code is not working. The task is to create a table like
this

[image]

This is the piece I did. Could you please help me out with pointing out at the mistake I made or parts missing in my code? Every help very much appreciated.

```js
const tableValues = new Array(10).fill(false).map((x, i) => {
  return new Array(10).fill(1).map((y, i2) => {
    return (i + 1) * i2
  })
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tableCreate, false);

function tableCreate() {
  const table = document.getElementById("table");
  tableValues.forEach((row) => {
    const row = document.createElement("tr")
    row.forEach(cell => {
        const cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.innerHTML = cellText;
        cell.appendChild(cellText)
      }
      row.appendChild(cell))
  })
  table.appendChild(body)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="table"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives a very useful error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your script without changing the code much. Study it and figure out what were the issues

Basically you had the appendChild outside both loops.
Also you used appendChild twice on the cell - you COULD have used a createTextNode on the value to use appendChild on the cellcontent

```js
const tableValues = new Array(10).fill(false).map((x, i) => {
  return new Array(10).fill(1).map((y, i2) => {
    return (i + 1) * i2
  })
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tableCreate, false);

function tableCreate() {
  const table = document.getElementById("table");
  tableValues.forEach(values => {
    const row = document.createElement("tr")
    values.forEach(value => {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.innerHTML = value;
      //cell.appendChild(cellText)
      row.appendChild(cell)
    })
    table.appendChild(row)
  })
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="table"></tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a shorter version

```js
const tableValues = new Array(10).fill(false).map((x, i) => new Array(10).fill(1).map((y, i2) => (i + 1) * i2))


const tableCreate = () => document.getElementById("table")
  .innerHTML = tableValues
    .map(values => `<tr>
      ${values
        .map(value => `<td>${value}</td>`).join('')} 
    </tr>`).join('');


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tableCreate);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="table"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I guess gotta dig into the stuff more.

Comment: See my update for more explanation